# How to display values from sql statement

Tags: java, sql

I am using netbeans.
I have a table 'incident' with column 'priority' which can hold values priority 1 , priority 2.

I have created a jcombobox with 3 options - select all( to select all the rows) / priority 1(to select rows with priority 1 and so on) / priority 2. Options are passed through prioritybox.getSelected().
I want to know any possible sql statement so that if i select the option 'select all' , all the entries of the table should be selected.

If i choose priority 1 
then the statement

```
  select * from incident where priority='"+prioritybox.getSelected()+"';
```

gets executed correctly i.e. it select the rows which having priority=priority1. But if i select the option 'select all ' then this statement becomes invalid as no such row is there with priority value = select all.I don't want to use if-else . Any other possible solution??

Comment: What is the problem with `if-else` ?

Comment: I will be including 9 more columns with this one. So  9! if-else will be needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use if clause.
Go with the following code

```
     String strSelect1 = "select * from table";
     if(prioritybox.getSelectedItem()!="your option")
     { strSelect1=strSelect1+" where Priority='"+prioritybox.getSelectedItem()+"'"; };
```

Now keep on adding this if statements for rest of the fields.

Answer (score 0):

For purely SQL you could do:

```
select * from incident where priority='"+prioritybox.getSelected()+"' OR '"+prioritybox.getSelected()+"' = 'select all';
```

However it's probably easier to add logic  to add the where clause if the option is not select all.

Comment: there is no 'select all' value in priority column. From 'select option' I want the sql to include the whole table.

Comment: The above SQL will do that. If select all is chosen the SQL where will be `WHERE priority='select all' OR 'select all'= 'select all'`. This will return all rows.

Comment: but there is no row having value 'select all' in priority column.

Comment: Because that's an `OR` statement and the second value is true though it will return all rows.

Answer (score 0):

```
String query="";
if(!prioritybox.getSelected().toString().equals("select all")){
    query="select * from incident where priority='"+prioritybox.getSelected()+"'";
}
else {
    query="select * from incident" ;

 }
```

Comment: string comparision using `!=`??

Comment: `!"select all".equals(prioritybox.getSelected())` !

Answer (score 0):

You can pass special character **'%'** to query which will return all characters for that you need to replace = with like query and you need to set '%' as your 'SelectAll' value, your query can be like this

```
select * from incident where priority like '"+prioritybox.getSelected()+"';
```